# SwiftUI - Form Picker & Button Not Co-Existing

Tags: swiftui

I have created a reusable component that has a picker, textfield and button within a form. However, with the button present, a tap on the picker field does not go to the picker. Rather it executes the button code. The TextField works fine. If I remove the button code, the proper behavior will occur with the picker. So the question is how to have both elements within this component? Please note that the preview adds the Navigation and Form which would otherwise come from the parent view.

```
var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if !showFee {
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3)) {
                        self.showFee.toggle()
                    }
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                }
                Spacer()
            } else {
                VStack(spacing:20) {
                    Picker(selection: $feeSelection, label: Text("Fee Type")) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< fees.count) {
                            Text(self.fees[$0])
                        }
                    }

                    TextField("Fee Amount: $", value: $feeAmount, formatter: NumberFormatter.currency)
                    .keyboardType(.decimalPad)

                    Divider()
                    Button(action: {
                        withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3)) {
                            self.showFee.toggle()
                        }
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "trash.circle.fill")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct FeeCell_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                FeeCell()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you can do is to apply the `PlainButtonStyle` to your button. This will stop the button's *tap* covering to the whole cell in the Form:

```
Button(action: {}) {
    Text("Button")
}
.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
```

Comment: My goodness, I spent untold hours on this issue just to have it be this one line. I can do much of UIKit in my sleep and I am getting humbled like a child with SwiftUI right now. Thank you!